# Spring WebFlux - Returning the value returned by Consumer invoked inside Mono.subscribe();

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm using a non-reactive repository and therefore I need to subscribe to the `Mono` which contains the entity, in order to save it in the datbase.
How do I return the value that is returned by `Consumer` invoked inside `Mono.subscribe()`?

```
public SomeEntity saveSomeEntity(Mono<SomeEntity> someEntityMono) {
    someEntityMono.subscribe(someEntity -> someEntityNotReactiveRepository.save(someEntity));
...
}
```

In this case I would like to return the result of `someEntityNotReactiveRepository.save(someEntity)`.

Maybe there is an alternative to using `subscribe()` (other than `block()`) which could help me achieve what I need?

Comment: sorry you have to block() somewhere. If your stack is not reactive all the way there is little point in using reactive approach. It's just a complexity booster. With no benefit.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification. Unfortunately I have no say in that matter. The management was all too eager to jump into reactive programming with Oracle 11 sitting pretty as our database.

Comment: I don't know the context so no judgment. Ask them if there is a long term plan. Because there are things that you can do here.